# Problems with OG private groups

Tags: organic-groups

I've installed a drupal commons site (7.x-3.23).
I'm trying to give ability to choose on group creation if the group content will be visible or not from non-members of the group.
So i've activated organic group access control, rebuilt permissions, added in OG the field 'group content visibility' to the commons group bundle. 
When i go to the group content type i see the field so it must be OK. 
But when i create or edit a group, i never see the option for privacy content. 
I opened the fields settings in group content type for the content visibility, and all seems fine in spite of the default value which is not displayed.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different fields:

- *Group visibility.* It only exists for Groups. It controls whether all group content is visible to non-members by default.
- *Group content access.* It only exists for Group content. It controls whether a particular node in the group is visible or invisible to non-members, or whether it should leave that decision to the default setting of the group.

Check whether your group has a group visibility field and whether you have the permissions to edit it, and if not, add that field via `/admin/config/group/fields` and grant the right permissions to edit it.